# Unknown option: package.json.presets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, decorator, mobx

I'm using **babel-core ^5.4.7** and **babel-loader ^5.1.2** with webpack. I'm also using **mobx ^3.3.1** and mobx-react ^4.3.3 version. Now my problem is when I'm trying to build my project by hitting npm run watch:webpack it throws **unknown option: package.json.presets**

here my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^5.4.7",
   "babel-eslint": "^3.1.9",
   "babel-loader": "^5.1.2",
   "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^1.1.1",
   "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
   ....
   "webpack": "^1.9.6",
   "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
   "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "mobx": "^3.3.1",
   "mobx-react": "^4.3.3",
   "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
   "react": "16.0.0",
   "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.5.4",
   "react-dom": "16.0.0",
   ....
 },
 "babel": {
   "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
   "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
 }
```

and here my webpack.config.dev.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var src = path.join(__dirname, 'engine');
var dest = path.join(__dirname, 'assets/builder');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    src + '/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: dest,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/builder/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components', src]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'FREE': process.argv.indexOf('--free') !== -1 ? JSON.stringify("free"): JSON.stringify("pro")
      }
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['babel?stage=0'], include: src},
      {test: /\.js?$/, loaders: ['babel?stage=0'], include: src},
      {test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css'},
      {test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/, loader: "url-loader"},

      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"},
      {test: /\.ttf?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=font/ttf"},
      {test: /\.(eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader"}
    ]
  }
};
```

Here my mobx store with decorator @observable

```
export default class ElementStore {

      @observable path = null,
      @observable visible = false,
      @observable list = sortElementsByName(elements),

      handle(handlerName, {path}) {
        switch (handlerName) {
          case HIDE_ELEMENTS:
            // do something..
            break;
          case SHOW_ELEMENTS:
            // do something..
            break;
        }
      }
  }
```

And the error message is

```
ERROR in ./engine/index.jsx
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/iftekhersunny/Documents/code/quix/src/lib_quix/engine/index.jsx: Unknown option: /Users/iftekhersunny/Documents/code/quix/src/lib_quix/package.json.presets
```

Why the presets is the unknown option???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`presets` is a config flag for Babel 6.x, and you're trying to use it with Babel 5. Babel 5 is super old, just use Babel 6.

Comment: babel-loader version??

Comment: now getting this error Module build failed: TypeError: fileSystem.statSync is not a function
    at module.exports (/Users/iftekhersunny/Documents/code/quix/src/lib_quix/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/utils/exists.js:7:25)

Comment: You also appear to be using extremely old versions of Webpack. That statSync API doesn't exist on older Webpack. Are you upgrading an existing project? It seems like if you were installing fresh, none of this would be an issue. Using a current version of babel-loader and Webpack should work fine.

Comment: yeah. my project is very old :( ok I'm upgrading webpack too

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove babel option from package.json file and create a `.babelrc` file in root of the project.

.babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react","stage-1"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

hope it works

Comment: now getting this error Unkown options .babelrc.presets :(

Comment: check out this link https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/132
may be it help you out